# When can I get pop2 opcode in a .class file compiled from Java source code?

Tags: java, bytecode, decompiler

I'm currently working on a Java decompiler.

I read the JVM specification, and I know `pop2` can operate one stack value (category 2 values) or two stack values (other category values).

I just want to know when a two stack values operation of `pop2` can happen? Could anyone show me some Java source code whose compilation result contains **two stack values operations** `pop2`?

Comment: pop2 (or any instruction in the JVM) only operates on **one** stack. Perhaps you mean "stack values" (the terminology in the JVM stack). The way your question is currently written, it doesn't make a lot of sense. In any case, pop2 pops 2 category 1 values (each category 1 value is 32 bits, so it pops 64 bits from the stack). Or it pops 1 category 2 value (each category 2 value is 64 bits, so it again pops 64 bits from the stack). pop2 just pops 64 bits or 8 bytes from the stack.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry, I mean "stack values". I have corrected my question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I think Stephen C gives me a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my brief reading of the source code for the `javac` compiler in Java 8, there are **no places** where it will emit a `POP2` to pop 2 category-1 values from the stack.  If two category-1 values need to be popped, then two `POP` bytecodes will be emitted by the compiler.

Caveats:

- I only looked at one version of the OpenJDK `javac` compiler
- there are other (non-Sun/Oracle) Java bytecode compilers
- bytecodes can be generated or modified by other means .... including code obfuscators!

---

It is plausible that the two value pop behavior of `POP2` was used in early Java bytecode compilers before the advent of JIT compilers.  But now that we have JIT compilers, there is *no point* in the bytecode compilers "optimizing" two `POP` bytecodes to a `POP2`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is also what I guess. I don't know C++, and I didn't try to read `javac` source code. I tried to construct some java programs, and for those programs the compiler never optimize two `pop` to one `pop2`. I also found some bytecodes with `pop2` pops two category 1 values, but none of them are generated by  `javac` from Java source code.

Comment: The `javac` compiler is written in Java.  No excuses :-)

Comment: I should be more brave! However, I'm trying to learn Java by writing a Java decompiler. I'm actually using Scala :-).

Comment: @JiannLan I don’t think that “trying to learn Java by writing a Java decompiler” is a feasible strategy. Besides that, I don’t get the purpose of your question. The way you would have to handle the `pop2` instruction, is straight-forward, so why do you think it matters whether the compiler actually uses it?

Comment: @Holger “trying to learn Java by writing a Java decompiler” is one of my purpose, and it is NOT the main purpose of the whole project. I don't care if it is feasible strategy. "How the compiler actually uses it" is my personal curious -- too many personal interest things I don't think they are useful when I describe the background of my question. I ask a question and I think the answer for this question is useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

POP2 will definitely be called if you pop a double or long, such as

thisMethodReturnsALong();
thisMethodReturnsADouble();

among other cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have mentioned that I know the cases that `pop2` can pop ONE category 2 stack value (I have corrected my question: I should say "stack values" rather than "stacks"). I hope to see Java code examples that `pop2`  pops two category 1 stack values.